How can I get notified of new MySQL releases?
I'd like to know when a new MySQL 8.4 patch version is released?
What's the easiest way to do that?
Currently, I have to manually go and check this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.4/en/

There is a service at WatchThatPage.com. They have a free tier.
You can sign up and set it to watch for changes to the https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.4/en/ page you mentioned, or any other page that might tell you about MySQL releases.
(I'm sure there are other similar services. This just happens to be one I learned about this week.)
Oracle also appears to have a notification service that you can subscribe to.
